# Can't make border-radius on DT

Tags: html, css

Why can't I make a `border-radius` on my `<dt>`?

http://thistedbolig.konggulerodhosting.dk/

What can I change? I really need to make the border-radius. I have tried many things, but none of them work. I hope someone here can help me so I can finish the project.

CSS:

```
.dropdown dt { border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">
          <dl class="dropdown">

            <dt>
            <a href="#0">
              <span title="city" class="hida " ><img src="assets/images/search/placeholder.svg" alt="" style="width:20px; height:20px; margin-right:10px;">Vælg en by</span>
              <p class="multiSel"></p>
            </a>
            </dt>

            <dd>
                <div class="mutliSelect">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Thisted" />Thisted</li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Snested" />Snested</li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Vesløs" />Vesløs</li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Nors" />Nors</li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Sennels" />Sennels</li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Østerild" />Østerild</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        </div>
```

Comment: How about `.dropdown dt { border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px; solid black !important}` ?

Comment: I am not sure `dt` is a block element. maybe you need to add display: block!

Comment: Are you trying to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/w5osp21r/ ?

Comment: So i need to add a width and height?

Comment: You don't have to, it works without height and width, but set a background-color, and of course display: block

Comment: Clear cache, check css cascade ...

Comment: It was because i had a background on my a tag..

Comment: So, it is working now?

Comment: You need to do your border on the <a> tag inside of your dl!

Comment: I checked on your site! It works when you apply the border radius to the a tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the border on the **a tag** in order to apply a border

Thus:

**Update:**

```
.dropdown dt { 
              height: 20px;
              line-height: 20px;
              display: block;
              background: black;
}


.dropdown dt a {
    padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

should work!

line-height will center the text vertically!

Check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9tgj0n5k/1/

Comment: you need the border on the a tag!

Comment: Yup, it was because i had a background on the a tag :D